# Kotlin Coroutines and Concurrency

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

**My application is the following:**

The user has a list of photos which all downloads when the app is fired up automatically and after each async block finished the work, those pictures will be shown in a Recyclerview.

I use Firebase Storage for "External" File Storage.
Whenever i download something from there i would like to save it to a local list variable so whenever the user rotates the screen, it won't fire up a new download query rather it takes it from the local temp storage.

I know that kotlin coroutines is not like in Java when creating a new Thread, it just switches between tasks really fast.

Since all async{} block, do i have to make sure no concurrent read-write happen?

Is using, for example, a lock is a good idea?

The viewModel:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
        val plantProfilePicList = mutableListOf<Deferred<Pair<String, ByteArray>>>()
        plantList.forEach { plant ->
            val plantDeferred =
                async { plantScreenRepository.getProfilePicture(plantId = plant.plantId) }
            plantProfilePicList.add(plantDeferred)
        }
        _profilePictureList.value = plantProfilePicList.awaitAll()
    }
```

The repositroy:

```
val profilePicture = remotePicture.plantProfilePicture(
    plantPicturePath = profilePicturePath(
        currentUser = currentUser,
        plantId = plantId,
    ),
    bufferSize = currentDownloadSize
)
result = Pair(plantId, profilePicture)
successFull = true
localPicture.savePicture(result)
```

The local storage:

```
class LocalPlantPictureStoreImpl : LocalPlantPictureStore {
    private val lock = ReentrantReadWriteLock()
    private val readLock = lock.readLock()
    private val writeLock = lock.writeLock()

    private val plantPictureList: MutableList<Pair<String, ByteArray>> = mutableListOf()

    override fun savePicture(plantPicture: Pair<String, ByteArray>) {
        writeLock.lock()
        plantPictureList.add(plantPicture)
        writeLock.unlock()
    }

    override fun getPicture(plantId: String): Pair<String, ByteArray>? {
        readLock.lock()
        val tempValue: Pair<String, ByteArray>? =
            plantPictureList.firstOrNull { it.first == plantId }
        readLock.unlock()
        return tempValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, coroutines run concurrently to each other, similarly to threads. It is not safe to modify lists, maps, etc. from multiple coroutines without synchronizing the access.

To synchronize coroutines you can use a [Mutex](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/):

```kotlin
private val writeLock = Mutex()

override fun savePicture(plantPicture: Pair<String, ByteArray>) {
    writeLock.withLock {
        plantPictureList.add(plantPicture)
    }
}
```

We should generally not use Java locks with coroutines as you do. The reason is that Java locks block the thread and we should always avoid blocking threads while running coroutines. In your case it could be acceptable as the critical section should be very quick to execute, but if you can, I would still suggest to make these functions suspend and use `Mutex`. Alternatively, you can invoke `savePicture()` using `Dispatchers.IO` which will at least delegate the blocking code to a separate thread pool.